# Footer won't stay down after i use float

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

I'm working on a responsive website. I have tried EVERYTHING and my footer won't stay down. It's because I used float:left. I don't want it to be fixed, i want it only to appear when i scroll to the bottom of the page. This is my code:

EDIT: ok so i took position:absolute out and now it works on the pages it didn't before. but on the pages where i didn't use float:left it doesn't work anymore.

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background-color: #24478f;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 4vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

#container figure {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

... 
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1000px) {
  #container figure {
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <figure>
    <a href="Portfolio.html#applications">
      <img src="../imgs/74599-200.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption>Multimedia Applications</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="Portfolio.html#retrieval">
      <img src="../imgs/info1600.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption>Information Retrieval</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="Portfolio.html#games">
      <img src="../imgs/3281-200.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption>Computer Games</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>

<footer>
    <p> Infia Abelha</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove position:absolute and it works

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background-color: #24478f;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 4vw;
  clear: both;
}

#container figure {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

... 
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1000px) {
  #container figure {
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <figure>
    <a href="Portfolio.html#applications">
      <img src="../imgs/74599-200.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption>Multimedia Applications</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="Portfolio.html#retrieval">
      <img src="../imgs/info1600.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption>Information Retrieval</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="Portfolio.html#games">
      <img src="../imgs/3281-200.png">
    </a>
    <figcaption>Computer Games</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</section>

<footer>
    <p> Infia Abelha</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: @VXp yes sure, remove: left, bottom, width, max-width

Answer (score 0):

in order to do that you can use min-height for your section like this

```
#container{min-height:500px}
```

and set footer position to relative

```
footer{position:relative}
```